# How to write a rule to define a method in ANTLR

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am creating a DSL with ANTLR and I want to define the following syntax

```
// study without parameters
study()
// study  with a single parameter
study(x = 1)
// study with several parameters
study(x = 1, x = 2)
```

here my grammer ,it allows the following input : `study(x=1x=2)`

```
study: 'study' '(' ( assign* | ( assign (',' assign)*) ) ')' NEWLINE;
assign: ID '=' (INT  | DATA );
INT :   [0-9]+ ;
DATA    : '"' ID '"' | '"' INT '"';
ID  :   [a-zA-Z]+ ;
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grammar allows `study(x=1x=2)` because `assign*` matches `x=1x=2`. If you don't want to allow input like that, you should remove the `assign*` alternative. To allow empty parameter lists, you can just make everything between the parentheses optional:

```
study: 'study' '(' (assign (',' assign)*)? ')' NEWLINE;
```